# select the distinct data from list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list which contains some properties and list. I want to select the unique records based on the property of inner list how can i achieve it using LINQ
Example 
List

```
{item1 = 1, item2=2,list{a1=l1,a2=l2,a3=l5},item3 =3}
{item1 = 21, item2=21,list{a1=l11,a2=l2,a3=l3},item3 =3}
{item1 = 31, item2=22,list{a1=l12,a2=l2,a3=l3},item3 =3}
{item1 = 41, item2=23,list{a1=l1,a2=l2,a3=l3},item3 =3}
```

I want to select the record which has distinct value of property "a1".If I found duplicate value of "a1" then i will compare value "a3" != "l5"

Expected Result:

```
{item1 = 21, item2=21,list{a1=l11,a2=l2,a3=l3},item3 =3}
{item1 = 31, item2=22,list{a1=l12,a2=l2,a3=l3},item3 =3}
{item1 = 41, item2=23,list{a1=l1,a2=l2,a3=l3},item3 =3}
```

Comment: Can you provide the structure of your classes ? I am not sure to understand how you built them (looks like dictionnary to me)

Comment: Leppie below is the similar structure

Answer (score 0):

First you want to GroupBy on your inner list a1 and then select within that grouping for a3!="l5".

```
List<foo> col = new List<foo>();
List<string> tmp = new List<string> {"l1","l2","l5"};
col.Add(new foo {item1 = 1, item2=2,lst=tmp,item3 =3});
tmp = new List<string> {"l11","l2","l3"};
col.Add(new foo {item1 = 21, item2=21,lst=tmp,item3 =3});
tmp = new List<string> {"l12","l2","l3"};
col.Add(new foo {item1 = 31, item2=22,lst=tmp,item3 =3});
tmp = new List<string> {"l1","l2","l3"};
col.Add(new foo {item1 = 41, item2=23,lst=tmp,item3 =3});

var qry = col.GroupBy(i => i.lst[0]).Select(g => g.Where(j => j.lst[2]!="l5"));
```

If there are multiple duplicates where your a3 is not "l5" you will get all of them so you may need to filter on something else if this is not desired.

Comment: Hi Jim thanks for try but in your case you are considering list of string whereas in my case it's also a list of object. So i.lst[index] may not possible.

Comment: In that case you can just access the elements of the sub-object.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Log
{
    public int DoneByEmpId { get; set; }
    public string DoneByEmpName { get; set; }

  }

public class Class1
{
    static void Range()
    {
        var array = new List<Log>() {new Log() {DoneByEmpId = 1,DoneByEmpName = "Jon"},
            new Log() { DoneByEmpId = 1, DoneByEmpName = "Jon" } ,
            new Log() { DoneByEmpId = 2, DoneByEmpName = "Max" },
            new Log() { DoneByEmpId = 2, DoneByEmpName = "Max" },
            new Log() { DoneByEmpId = 3, DoneByEmpName = "Peter" }};

        var ordered =
            array.GroupBy(x => x.DoneByEmpId).ToList().Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).OrderBy(x => x.DoneByEmpName);
        foreach (var item in ordered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.DoneByEmpName);
        }
    }
}
```

Result : 

Jon

Max

Peter